# How to numerically solve this system?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerics, numerical-value

Our system:

\begin{align}
\dot S &= \mu  -\beta_1 S I_2 -\beta_2 S J-\beta_3 S A - \nu S\\[2ex]
\dot {I_1} &= p \beta_1 S I_1 +q \beta_2 S J +r \beta_3 S A + \xi_1 J- b_1 I_1   \\[2ex]
\dot{I_2} &=(1 - p) \beta_1 S I_2  + (1 - q) \beta_2 S J + (1 - r) \beta_3 S A + \epsilon I_1+ \xi_2 J - b_2 I_2  \\[2ex]
\dot{J} &=p_1 I_2 -b_3 J \\[2ex]
\dot{A} &= p_2 J -b_4 A
\end{align}

With $N= S+I_1+I_2 +J+A$. Implying $$\dot N = \mu - \nu N -\alpha A \leq \mu-\nu N $$

I tried:

```
tmax = 1000;
\[Beta]1 = 0.2;
\[Beta]2 = 0.1;
\[Beta]3 = 0.1;
p = 0.8;
q = 0.9;
r = 0.7;
\[Xi]1 = 0.1;
\[Xi]2 = 0.3;
\[Epsilon] = 0.2;
b1 = 0.4;
b2 = 0.3;
b3 = 0.5;
b4 = 0.2;
p1 = 0.3;
p2 = 0.2;
\[Mu] = 0.3;
\[Nu] = 0.1;
SIIJA = NDSolveValue[{
    S'[t] == \[Mu] - \[Beta]1*S[t]*I2[t] - \[Beta]2*S[t]*
       J[t] - \[Beta]3*S[t]*A[t] - \[Nu]*S[t],
    I1'[t] == 
     p*\[Beta]1*S[t]*I2[t] + q*\[Beta]2*S[t]*J[t] + 
      r*\[Beta]3*S[t]*A[t] + \[Xi]1 *J[t] - b1*I1[t],
    I2'[t] == (1 - p) \[Beta]1*S[t]*I2[t] + (1 - q)*\[Beta]2*S[t]*
       J[t] + (1 - r)*\[Beta]3*S[t]*A[t] + \[Epsilon]*I1[t] + \[Xi]2*
       J[t] - b2*I2[t],
    J'[t] == p1*I2[t] - b3*J[t],
    A'[t] == p2*J[t] - b4*A[t] ,
    S[0] == 50,
    I1[0] == 50,
    I2[0] == 50,
    A[0] == 10,
    J[0] == 10},
   {S, I1, I2, J, A},
   {t, 0, tmax}];
{f1, f2, f3, f4, f5} = SIIJA;

st = Style[#, 15, Black] &;

Plot[{f1[t], f2[t], f3[t], f4[t], f5[t]}, {t, 0, tmax}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, Purple, Yellow, Orange, Red}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> st /@ {"Time", "Density"}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[LineLegend[{Blue, Purple, Yellow, Orange, Red}, {"S(t)", 
     "I1(t)", "I2(t)", "J(t)", "A(t)" }, 
    LegendFunction -> Framed], {0.85, 0.65}], ImageSize -> 500]
```

but this doesn't seem correct..

**EDIT:**

Our "full" system:

```
    tmax = 1000;
\[Beta]1 = 0.00001;
\[Beta]2 = 0.0006;
\[Beta]3 = 0.00001;
p = 0.9;
q = 0.8;
r = 0.3;
\[Xi]1 = 0.8;
\[Xi]2 = 0.9;
\[Epsilon] = 0.0002;
p1 = 0.01;
p2 = 0.03;
\[Alpha] = 0.01;
\[Mu] = 0.55;
\[Nu] = 0.01;
SIIJA = NDSolveValue[{
    S'[t] == \[Mu] - \[Beta]1*S[t]*I2[t] - \[Beta]2*S[t]*
       J[t] - \[Beta]3*S[t]*A[t] - \[Nu]*S[t],
    I1'[t] == 
     p*\[Beta]1*S[t]*I2[t] + q*\[Beta]2*S[t]*J[t] + 
      r*\[Beta]3*S[t]*A[t] + \[Xi]1 *J[t] - (\[Epsilon] + \[Nu])*I1[t],
    I2'[t] == (1 - p) \[Beta]1*S[t]*I2[t] + (1 - q)*\[Beta]2*S[t]*
       J[t] + (1 - r)*\[Beta]3*S[t]*A[t] + \[Epsilon]*I1[t] + \[Xi]2*
       J[t] - (p1 + \[Nu])*I2[t],
    J'[t] == p1*I2[t] - (\[Xi]1 + \[Xi]2 + p2 + \[Nu])*J[t],
    A'[t] == p2*J[t] - (\[Alpha] + \[Nu])*A[t] ,
    S[0] == 50,
    I1[0] == 50,
    I2[0] == 50,
    J[0] == 10,
    A[0] == 10},
   {S, I1, I2, J, A},
   {t, 0, tmax}];
{f1, f2, f3, f4, f5} = SIIJA;

st = Style[#, 15, Black] &;

Plot[{f1[t], f2[t], f3[t], f4[t], f5[t]}, {t, 0, tmax}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, Purple, Yellow, Orange, Red}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> st /@ {"Time", "Density"}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[LineLegend[{Blue, Purple, Yellow, Orange, Red}, {"S(t)", 
     "I1(t)", "I2(t)", "J(t)", "A(t)" }, 
    LegendFunction -> Framed], {0.85, 0.75}], ImageSize -> 750]
```

**EDIT 2:**

Their plots(in the paper attached) are different to the plots I got when I modelled the same system, is there a reason why?

https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/S0307904X12002442?token=7F92FD800A67CDC6EBADE29BD17894CAE44E83139073043B925BCFE37615DC4CD3483D225B3EF9B55F9CE61DCD117F59&originRegion=eu-west-1&originCreation=20211130120104

```
tmax = 2000;
\[Beta]1 = 0.0001;
\[Beta]2 = 0.006;
p = 0.9;
q = 0.8;
\[Xi]1 = 0.8;
\[Xi]2 = 0.9;
\[Epsilon] = 0.002;
p1 = 0.01;
p2 = 0.03;
\[Alpha] = 0.01;
\[Mu] = 0.01;
\[Nu] = 0.55;
SIIJA = NDSolveValue[{
    S'[t] == \[Nu] - \[Beta]1*S[t]*I2[t] - \[Beta]2*S[t]*J[t] - \[Mu]*
       S[t],
    I1'[t] == 
     p*\[Beta]1*S[t]*I2[t] + 
      q*\[Beta]2*S[t]*J[t] + \[Xi]1 *J[t] - (\[Epsilon] + \[Mu])*I1[t],
    I2'[t] == (1 - p) \[Beta]1*S[t]*I2[t] + (1 - q)*\[Beta]2*S[t]*
       J[t] + \[Epsilon]*I1[t] + \[Xi]2*J[t] - (p1 + \[Mu])*I2[t],
    J'[t] == p1*I2[t] - (\[Xi]1 + \[Xi]2 + p2 + \[Mu])*J[t],
    A'[t] == p2*J[t] - (\[Alpha] + \[Mu])*A[t] ,
    S[0] == 50,
    I1[0] == 50,
    I2[0] == 50,
    J[0] == 20,
    A[0] == 20},
   {S, I1, I2, J, A},
   {t, 0, tmax}];
{f1, f2, f3, f4, f5} = SIIJA;

st = Style[#, 15, Black] &;

Plot[{f1[t], f2[t], f3[t], f4[t], f5[t]}, {t, 0, tmax}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, Purple, Yellow, Orange, Red}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> st /@ {"Time", "Density"}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[LineLegend[{Blue, Purple, Yellow, Orange, Red}, {"S(t)", 
     "I1(t)", "I2(t)", "J(t)", "A(t)" }, 
    LegendFunction -> Framed], {0.85, 0.45}], ImageSize -> 500]
```

Here is the reproduction number:

```
r0 = ((\[Beta]1 b3 (\[Epsilon] p + 
          b1 (1 - p)) + \[Beta]2 p1 (\[Epsilon] q + 
          b1 (1 - q))) (\[Nu]/\[Mu]))/(b1 b2 b3 - (\[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 +
         b1 \[Xi]2) p1);
```

**EDIT 3**

```
tmax = 2000;
\[Beta]1 = 0.0001;
\[Beta]2 = 0.006;
p = 0.3;
q = 0.4;
\[Xi]1 = 0.001;
\[Xi]2 = 0.003;
\[Epsilon] = 0.0002;
p1 = 0.01;
p2 = 0.03;
\[Alpha] = 0.01;
\[Mu] = 0.01;
\[Nu] = 0.55;
SIIJA = NDSolveValue[{
    S'[t] == \[Nu] - \[Beta]1*S[t]*I2[t] - \[Beta]2*S[t]*J[t] - \[Mu]*
       S[t],
    I1'[t] == 
     p*\[Beta]1*S[t]*I2[t] + 
      q*\[Beta]2*S[t]*J[t] + \[Xi]1 *J[t] - (\[Epsilon] + \[Mu])*I1[t],
    I2'[t] == (1 - p) \[Beta]1*S[t]*I2[t] + (1 - q)*\[Beta]2*S[t]*
       J[t] + \[Epsilon]*I1[t] + \[Xi]2*J[t] - (p1 + \[Mu])*I2[t],
    J'[t] == p1*I2[t] - (\[Xi]1 + \[Xi]2 + p2 + \[Mu])*J[t],
    A'[t] == p2*J[t] - (\[Alpha] + \[Mu])*A[t] ,
    S[0] == 50,
    I1[0] == 50,
    I2[0] == 50,
    J[0] == 20,
    A[0] == 20},
   {S, I1, I2, J, A},
   {t, 0, tmax}];
{f1, f2, f3, f4, f5} = SIIJA;

st = Style[#, 15, Black] &;

Plot[{f1[t], f2[t], f3[t], f4[t], f5[t]}, {t, 0, tmax}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, Purple, Yellow, Orange, Red}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> st /@ {"Time", "Density"}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[LineLegend[{Blue, Purple, Yellow, Orange, Red}, {"S(t)", 
     "I1(t)", "I2(t)", "J(t)", "A(t)" }, 
    LegendFunction -> Framed], {0.85, 0.75}], ImageSize -> 500]
```

We know a priori that $N(2000)$ should be approximately $55$. however from the model above if we do `f1[2000] + f2[2000] + f3[2000] + f4[2000] + f5[2000]` it gives `51.3631`. This is what I was trying to explain to Ulrich.

Comment: Correct the typo, double I2, in SIIJA :  `{S, I2, I2, J, A} `

Comment: @Akku14 Thanks, however $A$ isn't still showing up? Also, I don't know how to include the condition $N=S+I_1+I_2+J+A$

Comment: There is a typo in your Plot-command: Change `f[5]` to `f5[t]`

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Thank you. However I still haven't accounted for $N=S+I_1+I_2+J+A$. Another model, very similar to this, got completely different plots..

Comment: @Math `Plot[Total@{f1[t], f2[t], f3[t], f4[t], f5[t]}, {t, 0, tmax}]` shows decreasing population : `N[0]==170]`, `N[1000]=1.44`

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Shouldn't population be approaching $\frac{\mu}{\nu}$?

Comment: @Math Check your equations: Adding the right hand sides of the ode's doesn't evaluate to the implication `N' [t]=\[Mu]-\[Nu] N[t]-\[Alfa] A[t]`!  What's the value of  `\[Alfa] `?

Comment: "doesn't seem correct" how?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Check edited question

Comment: @ChrisK Why is there a sudden jump from $S(0)$ to almost $0$ for the susceptibles?

Comment: I will change the parameter values, let me see what I find.

Comment: Your implication is only true if you require `q==1` or `\[Beta]1 ==  \[Beta]2`!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann What implication? the condition for $N$?

Comment: @Math  You wrote in your question ` ...Implying N' [t]=\[Mu]-\[Nu] N[t]-\[Alfa] A[t]`

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Summing up all the equations does give that condition regardless of the values for $p, q, r$ and$\beta_1, \beta_2, \beta_3$

Comment: @Math That's what I recommended and did with a fresh kernel: `Collect[Np - (\[Mu] - \[Nu] (S[t] + I1[t] + I2[t] + J[t] + 
       A[t]) - \[Alpha] A[t]), {S[t], I1[t], I2[t], J[t], 
  A[t]}, Simplify]` evaluates to `-((-1 + q) (\[Beta]1 - \[Beta]2) J[t] S[t])`

Comment: @UlrichNeumann We can verify just by looking at the equations. Let me try using MM

Comment: @Math `S'[0] == -604.5` so it's not surprising that `S[t]` quickly approaches zero.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann sorry, I made a typo. I will correct the question

Comment: @ChrisK Yes, I was using wrong parameter values which is why I saw strange behaviour. Correct parameter values will be edited shortly. We can vary $p,q,r$ and $\beta_1, \beta_2, \beta_3$

Comment: @Math What exactly is the question?

Comment: @ChrisK I was looking at this paper: https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/S0307904X12002442?token=4B63665209E04539D766BB72E8BA583AD319DC43C49BF6196557E7937EBF6C51AB0EC85FC908E739D678B0B1209EDF5A&originRegion=eu-west-1&originCreation=20211129121533, when I tried modelling their identical system, the plots came out a little different, do you have any idea why? from the model I posted, just kill the $\beta_3$ terms and you'll have their system. See if you can match their plots. Most parameter values are in the table on page 1481 and the remaining are on page 1487.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann How do I verify that $S+I_1+I_2+J+A$ equals to $N$ at each point in time?

Comment: @ChrisK Did you manage to duplicate the plots? I'm certain I have the right code/parameters inputted but getting different plots to theirs, do you know why?

Comment: @Math Sorry, bad timing for me

Comment: @ChrisK No problem, Sir. Whenever you have time, please have a look! I do, truly appreciate your help/assistance for answering my past and present questions.

Comment: @math As far as I remember the definition is  `N=S+I1+I2+J+A`, nothing to verify!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I mean, at each point in time, this equality must hold. But we haven't included this in our model, maybe this is why my plots do not match the plots in the paper? I mean if we sum up all equations we have $\dot N$ and if we solve for $N$ we obtain a function for the total population at at time $t$. Then we can check if our numerical results($S+I1+I2+J+A$) do indeed equal to the function of $N(t)$ at a particular $t$.

Comment: @Math Your model  doesn't contain `N[t]` , `N[t]`follows from definition `N=S+I1+I2+J+A`

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Please look at Edit 3. This is what I've been trying to explain! I will go home now so I will check for responses tomorrow. I have a headache..

Comment: @ChrisK So the issue with edit 3 is answered, thank you. However, edit 2 is still a mystery, I would appreciate your take on it.